# Factorization into prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I citate Serge Lang's Algebra (Second edition, page 23).

If $A$ is a discrete valuation ring, then in particular, $A$ is a principal ideal ring, and any finitely generated torsion-free module $M$ over $A$ is free. If its rank is $n$, and if $\mathfrak{p}$ is the maximal ideal of $A$, then $M/\mathfrak{p}M$ is a free module of rank $n$.

**Proposition 19.** Let $A$ be a local ring and $M$ a free module of rank $n$ over $A$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the maximal ideal of $A$. Then $M/\mathfrak{p}M$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over $A/\mathfrak{p}$.

*Proof.* [...]

Let $A$ be a Dedekind ring, $K$ its quotient field, $L$ a finite separable extension of $K$, and $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, then $\mathfrak{p}B$ is an ideal of $B$ and has a factorization $$ \mathfrak{p}B = \mathfrak{B}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{B}_r^{e_r} \quad (e_i \geq 1)$$ into primes of $B$. It is clear that a prime $\mathfrak{B}$ of $B$ occurs in this factorization if and only if $\mathfrak{B}$ lies above $\mathfrak{p}$.

I'm having difficulties understanding this last section. I can see why a prime $\mathfrak{B}$ of $B$ occurs in this factorization if and only if $\mathfrak{B}$ lies above $\mathfrak{p}$ given that there exists a factorization. I don't know why there must exist such a factorization since $B$ is not a Dedekind ring (is it? I didn't come across a proof yet). The 'only' thing I know about $B$ from previous theorems and propositions is that $B$ is a free module of rank $n$ over $A$. Any help understanding this section?

Added note: apparently $B$ is Dedekind. However Lang does not use this fact to formulate this statement. Do I have to find a proof by reading between the lines or don't you need this fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $B$ is Dedekind.  There is a proof, for example, [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/MISC/Dedekind.pdf) (and probably in Lang somewhere, but I don't have the book handy).

Comment: Interestingly enough, Lang doesn't seem to mention this. I checked starting in section I.6 (Dedekind rings), up until the point where this fact is used in I.7 (bottom of pg. 23 of the second edition) and it is not there.